# "No endpoint listening" when starting an Azure web role under Compute Emulator

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-compute-emulator

I have two cloud solutions (.ccproj files). Each has a single distinct web role. One project runs under Compute Emulator without any problems but when I try to run another one (the first one not running) Visual Studio will package it and then display

> Windows Azure Tools: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/dfagent/2/host that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> Windows Azure Tools: The Windows Azure compute emulator is not running or responding. Stopping the debugging session.

I'm using SDK version 1.4

I Googled for a while but couldn't find anything that could help me. Force starting the Compute Emulator (`csrun /devfabric:start`) doesn't seem to help.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: It looks like something in your role is trying to call an external service and can't find it, is that the first role? can you expand on your scneario? have you tried capturing the exception and seeing what throws it?

Comment: @Yossi Dahan: Well, that's the only role and looks like I've provided all the information I had so far.

Answer (score 1):

Although an old question, I got this issue recently and the reason for it was that - while the service or website in azure would have been removed or stopped and you try to publish to it. If this happens, check the publish profile to see that you are pointing to the correct service/site including the storage acc etc and correct them. Hope it helps someone.